# Loop through nested array in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to loop through a nested array which is in my JSONObject. My aim is to echo div's based on the data in the JSONObject currently I am using this to get the contents of the JSON

```
$restaurant = json_decode(file_get_contents("restaurant.json"));
```

Here is the old foreach loop before I nested the array

```
<?php foreach($restaurant->menu->starter as $starter){
               echo '<h3>'.$starter->name.'</h3><br><p>'.$starter->price.'</p><br>'; 

           } ?>
```

And here is my new JSONObject

```
{
  "name": "Takeaway Kings",
  "menu": [
    {
      "starter": [
        {
          "name": "Samosas",
          "price": 3.5
        },
        {
          "name": "Chaat",
          "price": 1.99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dessert": [
        {
          "name": "Kulfi",
          "price": 2.5
        },
        {
          "name": "Kheer",
          "price": 2.99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "main": [
        {
          "name": "Lamb Biryani",
          "price": 4.5
        },
        {
          "name": "Chicken Tikka Masala",
          "price": 5.99
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure how to for example write this loop just for the starters data to display

Comment: Why did you make your data structure harder to traverse? Unless you are confident the ordering will never change, this new structure does not allow direct access to the properties you require

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288287/loop-through-json-array-inside-an-array/35288581#35288581

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = json_decode($json); // $json is your JSON.
foreach($arr->menu[0]->starter as $starter){
  echo '<h3>'.$starter->name.'</h3><br><p>'.$starter->price.'</p><br>';
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a foreach to loop through each array so starter main and dessert and then a nested foreach loop to loop through each arrays content. I was thinking of echoing out the div if the content is present if not then do not display it