# Javascript/Jquery Loop through object values inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var object =   [{
      "mainMenu": "MainMenu1",
      "Submenu": [
        {
          "SubMenu1": [
            { "name": "SubMenu1 page1", "access": "Read" },
            { "name": "SubMenu1 page2", "access": "Write" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "SubMenu2": [
            { "name": "SubMenu2 page1", "access": "Read" },
            { "name": "SubMenu2 page2", "access": "Write" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "SubMenu3": [
            { "name": "SubMenu3 page1", "access": "Read" },
            { "name": "SubMenu3 page2", "access": "Write" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "mainMenu": "MainMenu1",
      "Submenu": [
        {
          "SubMenu1": [
            { "name": "SubMenu1 page1", "access": "Read" },
            { "name": "SubMenu1 page2", "access": "Write" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "SubMenu2": [
            { "name": "SubMenu2 page1", "access": "Read" },
            { "name": "SubMenu2 page2", "access": "Write" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "SubMenu3": [
            { "name": "SubMenu3page1", "access": "Read" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
```

I've got an array looking like one above. I'd like to loop through each object and get the values. How can this be done in Javascript/jQuery?

I tried using:

```
for (var key1 in object) {
  var e1 = object[key1];
  for (var key2 in e1) {
    var e2 = e1[key2];
    //console.log(e2);
    for (var key3 in e2) {
      console.log(e2);
      console.log(e2[key3]);
      $(".div1").append("<div class='main'><h4>"+e1+"</h4><ul><li>"+e2[key2]+"<ul><li>Sub Menu1</li><li>Sub Menu2</li></ul></li><li>"+e2[key2]+"<ul><li>Sub Menu1</li><li>Sub Menu2</li></ul></li></ul>");

    }
  }
}
```

i found in PHP Code in below link i need to do it in Javascript/Jquery

[PHP code Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288287/loop-through-json-array-inside-an-array)

Comment: There is no `obj2` in your first example. Which element are you trying to actually read in that one? Also, does the sample code you gave actually do anything right now?

Comment: @samanime i forgot to assign data to variable updated the code, i need to loop all values of object in list in this link you will find how HTML Look like https://jsfiddle.net/n2h4j7rg/